# Two network interfaces, one randomly fails

Tags: linux, networking, routing, lan

I have a desktop (named "D") and a laptop ("L") connected by ethernet to a router ("Wormhole").  This router only serves to connect these two computers.  Additionally, I have a wifi router ("WiFi") elsewhere, and both computers also connect to it.  The topology expands from there, but the details aren't important.  The Wormhole connection exists to speed up data transfers between these two machines.  (Note: I've been informed that I'm using the word "router" incorrectly here.  What I mean is the switching side of the device that is collectively called a router.)

WiFi handles 192.168.4.1/24 and external addresses; Wormhole only handles 192.168.8.1/24.  Additionally, WiFi uses DHCP, but Wormhole's clients have static IPs.  D's Wormhole address is 192.168.8.8 and L is 192.168.8.6.  D's Wifi connection is through wlan0 and Wormhole through eth0 as you'd expect.

**Some of the time this works fine** and traffic between 192.168.8.8 and 192.168.8.6 is speedy.  But, seemingly randomly after D boots up, **sometimes D can't reach Wormhole** until we throw the dice again at the next reboot.  As a workaround, D and L can still talk without an issue via their WiFi connections.

`ping -c4 192.168.8.1`:

```
PING 192.168.8.1 (192.168.8.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.8.8 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.8.8 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.8.8 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.8.8 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.8.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3035ms
```

Sometimes, rebooting D clears this problem, but sometimes not.  I am certain the problem is not with the router or the cable, as I can swap out D for other systems and everything works again.  L never seems to have a problem.

D runs Ubuntu 21.10 (actually, Kubuntu).  Initially, I suspected that the routes were being influenced by a race condition during initialization or something, but really I only thought that because I'm out of my depth. I've recorded the output of `route`, `ip route`, `ip route show to match 192.168.8.1`, `ip a`, and `nmcli device show`, all during when the connection works and when it doesn't work.  The output is identical, which I find shocking, and why I'm writing up this plea.  The only parts that are different in `ip a` is what you'd expect, like wlan0's DHCPv6 address and LFT stats.

`route`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         WiFi            0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.8.0     192.168.8.1     255.255.255.0   UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

`ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.4.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.4.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.4.102 metric 600 
192.168.8.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.8 metric 100 
192.168.8.0/24 via 192.168.8.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
```

`ip route show to match 192.168.8.1`:

```
default via 192.168.4.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600 
192.168.8.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.8 metric 100 
192.168.8.0/24 via 192.168.8.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
```

`ip address show dev eth0`:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:3f:49:a5:03:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s25
    inet 192.168.8.8/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3a41:15c1:b87a:5f63/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`nmcli device show eth0`:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         E0:3F:49:A5:03:D6
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.8.8/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.8.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 192.168.8.0/24, nh = 192.168.8.1, mt = 100
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::3a41:15c1:b87a:5f63/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
```

I've tried messing around with netplan and /etc/network/interfaces, but I'm just stabbing in the dark.  The last time I set up networking in Linux was before systemd took over, and configuration was a lot different back then.  Not that I know much about network troubleshooting in the first place.  Any ideas?

Comment: Run wireshark on both ends when you ping. Check logs for errors. Run ifdown/ifup on the 
ethernet interface. Run ethtool on the ethernet  interface and check what is returned, particularly speed and duplex when it works and when it stops working.

Comment: You are routing 192.168.8.0/24 via your default gateway 192.168.4.1, is this intentional?

Comment: @Bib - Right now I'm in a "doesn't work" state.  Wireshark sees the ping attempts but it doesn't get past the ARP broadcast, what it describes as "Who has 192.168.8.1? Tell 192.168.8.8".  I don't get responses from that.  I'm not exactly sure what I'm supposed to look for in ethtools, but `ethtool eth0` shows full duplex and 1000Mb/s speed.

@mashuptwice - No, definition not intentional nor desired.  Do you see that in the `ip route show to match` command?

Comment: @Sorensen no, in the `ip route` output. It seems like you have 192.168.4.1 set as default gateway and a duplicate entry for 192.168.8.0/24. From my understanding you'll need to set the default gateway to your "nearest" router, in this case 192.168.8.1. Then 192.168.8.1 should handle the routing to 192.168.4.1 by itself. At the moment you are trying to send the packets to 192.168.8.0/24 via the gateway 192.168.4.1, which cannot work as 4.1 is behind 8.1. Could you confirm that theory with a `traceroute` in both functional and fault state?

Comment: @mashuptwice `ip route get to 192.168.8.1` would clarify the "issue" (it would show the correct interface without having to second guess). That's because OP used the `match` flag that multiple routes are displayed ("match PREFIX selects routes with prefixes not longer than PREFIX." shorter prefixes means wider routes so will always include the default route, relevant to the parameter given or not).

Comment: @mashuptwice @A.B 192.168.4.1 should be the default gateway; everything other than 192.168.8.0/24 should go through 192.168.4.1.  The Wormhole router isn't connected to the WiFi router in any way, it only serves as a direct connection between D and L.  `traceroute` doesn't show anything since none of this is technically routing, it's all on the same one of two networks. Currently I'm in a functioning state and `ip route get to 192.168.8.1` returns `192.168.8.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.8.8 uid 1000` and `cache`.  I'll run it again in a broken state next time it flips.

Comment: (PS, @A.B Thanks for the info on `match`, I did not know that.)

Comment: To rule out any interaction with Docker and unrelated firewall settings, next time this happens, could you run `rmmod br_netfilter` (which might affect Docker which loaded it, but the goal is to see if it fixes something)?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a duplicate `192.168.8.1` somewhere on the network(s)?

Comment: @Sorensen any updates?

Comment: @mashuptwice Last week, it was easy to get into a fail state and hard for it to succeed.  This week, it's the reverse, and I cannot explain why.  I haven't been able to get into a fail state to test taking down Docker.  I'm certain I don't have a duplicate `192.168.8.1` anywhere though; I don't see how one could possibly be established.  I'll update this if I can get into a fail state again.